# Magento: where can I find a status state order flow?

Tags: magento

I need to change the flow of the order and I found it quite confusing so I would like to have flowchart of it.

I found a good one but it is german: 
http://magento.xonu.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/magento-status-state-flow.png

Comment: [Magento Order State&Status Flow](https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/magento-order-statestatus-flow) was linked to in a deteled answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After Some Google I have found some link may this help you :

Order Flow Diagram:  http://www.gliffy.com/publish/1774620/

Some Other Article explaining Complete Order Process:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_8

<strike>http://www.ecomdev.org/2012/08/28/magento-checkout-functionality-concept.html</strike>

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-quote-order-invoice-workflow/

Hope this Help !!